# ORMLite ManyToOne's friend JoinColumn annotation not handled

Tags: many-to-one, ormlite

I have been fiddling with ormlite on android. It's early days and so far I really like what I have seen.

While reading the manual I noticed the ability to use `javax.persistence` annotation instead of the default. When trying to define a `@ManyToOne` relationship I cam a little unstuck. Normally I use a `@JoinColumn(name="xxx")` to defined the column name with a `@ManyToOne`, ie. not the `@Column(name="xxx")`. Am I right, or should I be looking at this a different way.

I had a quick look and thought a few small additions to `com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistence.java` would resolve this issue. Basically the duplicating the code to handle the `@Column` to instead handle the `@JoinColumn` (maybe without the "length").

This also left me wondering is there were any issues with using both the standard ormlite annotations as well as the `javax.persistence` ones. Questions like:

- do the standard annotations take precedence?, and
- can the processing of `javax.persistence` annotations be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately @user928550, the `javax.persistence` annotations are not completely supported by [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  The limited support for them is defined in the manual:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/jpa

I'd be happy to improve the support for them if you want to make suggestions about how to proceed.  Please use the ORMLite developers mailing list to suggest your additions:

> http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-dev

In answer to you specific questions, existence of the `@DatabaseField` annotation will override any `javax.persistence` annotation processing and you cannot disable the processing of `javax.persistence` (unless you specify a `@DatabaseField`).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have followed you suggestion and added my suggestions as you recommended